# Как вставить свой блок навигации с помощью catalog.hml?

Tags: magento, navigationbar

Имеется измененный файл (аналог left.phtml, находящиеся в catalog/navigation. Он выводит нужные категории в список.
Вопрос заключается в том где в catalog.hml правильно вставить ссылку на этот файл, чтобы в левой колонке выводился всегда список нужных категорий и при этом ниже оставался блок "фильтры"?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного теории :)

Вам стоит почитать документацию по Layouts http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-4.html

Если кратко, в шаблоне вызывается метод отображающий левый блок следующим образом:

```
<?php if ($_leftContent = $this->getChildHtml('left_first')): ?>
    <div class="col-left sidebar col-left-first"><?php echo $_leftContent;   ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

А то, что находится в блоке определяется в файле app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/catalog.xml

В catalog.xml есть два варианта для категорий - это Anchor и Non-Anchor.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По умолчанию, для Non-Anchor используется "Список категорий" catalog/navigation/left.phtml, а для Anchor - "Расширенная навигация" (фильтр) - catalog/layer/view.phtml.

Вообще расширенная навигация тоже может отображать список категорий (чтобы не городить блоки).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить вашу задачу:

1. Найти в файле app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/catalog.xml тег catalog_category_layered, а в нем reference name="left_first".
2. Добавить внутрь block, чтобы получилось следующим образом:

```html
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="left_first">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav.browse" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
        </block>
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
        </block>
    </reference>
    ...
```

Comment: Благодарю за ваш труд и помощь, Danil!!!